# openfire offile notification/trigger

Tags: php, sockets, openfire

I am using openfire for chat application in iOs and php website. and everything is working fine.

I have also implemented push notifications when opponent user is offline and you are sending a message to that user (in short push notification for offline message). I have implemented above stuff which is available here : [Openfire offline notification through PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822205/openfire-offline-notification-through-php)

Now, client asks me to implement one more feature which includes :

- Send mail to admin when any user goes offline.

But now there is no any hook available to track user status. So how to implement the same ?

**What I tried**

I also tried one trick in which I am sending broadcast message to all users and if any user is offile then my **CallbackOnOffline** plugin will invoke, but here its **not sending broadcast message to offline users**.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to "intercept" Presence packet with `Presence.Type.unavailable`

Openfire has a ConnectionCloseListener (in SessionManager class) that fires a Presence unavailable.

If you read the class comments, it says

```
  // Send an unavailable presence to the user's subscribers
  // Note: This gives us a chance to send an unavailable presence to the
  // entities that the user sent directed presences
```

so probably it's possible to have an administrative user who can auto-subscribe to all users, recive the presence-unavailable and so you'll be able to just intercept the packet direct to this user to send your e-mail.

With opposite logic you'll be able to force a direct presence to something you control and intercept presence-unavailable to this entity

Comment: I am 100% agree with your logic, but the problem is over here I need to keep one user logged-in all the time in the browser, where I can implement listener and can fire ajax based on that. But what if no one is logged-in to system and want to track users presence ??? is it possible to trigger any url same as CallbackOnOffline plugin ?

Comment: With Openfire (so I bet also with any other server), you can intercept a kind of Stanza (Presence) and if needed add a filter (example: "to=admin@adminmessages"). So, just intercept any Presence ad do your staff or add and administrative user by default (you can duplicate the Presence, or just force a subscription and so on). In theory you don't need a client always online, you'll just have to add a prerequisite to let Openfire send the Presence. You'll intercept the presence before openfire "realize" admin it's offline

Comment: "add a prerequisite to let Openfire send the Presence" but here send to whom ? I want to call one php script on offline, is that possible ?

Comment: Well dude, it's all possible. You can intercept the Presence, on intercept you can do all what you want, also a call on a servlet that call a php script, call a ws that invoke a php script, an update on a database with a php job that consume this database and so on. But this is really out of the original question and you know your architecture ;)

Comment: Is it possible for you to chat more on the same at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114182/room-for-er-kt-and-mrpk ?