# Best way to notify offline user message Android Xmpp Chat using openFire

Tags: android

I am creating a chat application in android and I am using asmack client to communicate with XMPP server(Openfire server). I want to know what other ways to notify offline user if any message comes and they have internet connection but offline from openfire server. I only think about google cloud messaging please suggest if any other solution.

Thanks !!!

Comment: How would you know about message if you are not connected with OpenFire server? If you want to send message even user is offline there is only option GCM and or APNS in iOS

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding CallbackOnOffline plugin in openfire.
you can find how it work from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822205/openfire-offline-notification-through-php)

For this You make one service for fire gcm push call.

Another way is create custom plugin in openfire.